# python can't see imported os library

Tags: python

i have following code

```
import os
from os  import *
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import librosa
import librosa.display
import pandas as pd
from pandarallel import pandarallel
pandarallel.initialize()
Base_Directory = "UltraSound/"
PATH = os.path.abspath(Base_Directory)
def feature_extractor(file_name):
    file_name = os.path.join(PATH, file_name)
    audio,sample_rate = librosa.load(file_name, res_type='kaiser_fast')
    mfccs_features = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40)
    mfccs_scaled_features = np.mean(mfccs_features.T, axis=0)
    return mfccs_scaled_features
"""
audio_file ='UltraSound/100263-2-0-3.wav'
signal,sample_rate =librosa.load(audio_file)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
plt.plot(signal)
plt.show()
"""
metadata =pd.read_csv('UltraSound/UrbanSound8K.csv')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    metadata['mfccs_scaled_features'] = metadata['slice_file_name'].parallel_apply(feature_extractor)
    print(metadata.head())
```

despite fact that os library is imported, it shows following error :

```
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

i dont know reason, should i locate all imports inside if statement? or what is the reason?
Here is complete  output :

```
INFO: Pandarallel will run on 6 workers.
INFO: Pandarallel will use standard multiprocessing data transfer (pipe) to transfer data between the main process and workers.

WARNING: You are on Windows. If you detect any issue with pandarallel, be sure you checked out the Troubleshooting page:
https://nalepae.github.io/pandarallel/troubleshooting/
INFO: Pandarallel will run on 6 workers.
INFO: Pandarallel will use standard multiprocessing data transfer (pipe) to transfer data between the main process and workers.

WARNING: You are on Windows. If you detect any issue with pandarallel, be sure you checked out the Troubleshooting page:
https://nalepae.github.io/pandarallel/troubleshooting/
INFO: Pandarallel will run on 6 workers.
INFO: Pandarallel will use standard multiprocessing data transfer (pipe) to transfer data between the main process and workers.

WARNING: You are on Windows. If you detect any issue with pandarallel, be sure you checked out the Troubleshooting page:
https://nalepae.github.io/pandarallel/troubleshooting/
INFO: Pandarallel will run on 6 workers.
INFO: Pandarallel will use standard multiprocessing data transfer (pipe) to transfer data between the main process and workers.

WARNING: You are on Windows. If you detect any issue with pandarallel, be sure you checked out the Troubleshooting page:
https://nalepae.github.io/pandarallel/troubleshooting/
INFO: Pandarallel will run on 6 workers.
INFO: Pandarallel will use standard multiprocessing data transfer (pipe) to transfer data between the main process and workers.

WARNING: You are on Windows. If you detect any issue with pandarallel, be sure you checked out the Troubleshooting page:
https://nalepae.github.io/pandarallel/troubleshooting/
INFO: Pandarallel will run on 6 workers.
INFO: Pandarallel will use standard multiprocessing data transfer (pipe) to transfer data between the main process and workers.

WARNING: You are on Windows. If you detect any issue with pandarallel, be sure you checked out the Troubleshooting page:
https://nalepae.github.io/pandarallel/troubleshooting/
INFO: Pandarallel will run on 6 workers.
INFO: Pandarallel will use standard multiprocessing data transfer (pipe) to transfer data between the main process and workers.

WARNING: You are on Windows. If you detect any issue with pandarallel, be sure you checked out the Troubleshooting page:
https://nalepae.github.io/pandarallel/troubleshooting/
INFO: Pandarallel will run on 6 workers.
INFO: Pandarallel will use standard multiprocessing data transfer (pipe) to transfer data between the main process and workers.

WARNING: You are on Windows. If you detect any issue with pandarallel, be sure you checked out the Troubleshooting page:
https://nalepae.github.io/pandarallel/troubleshooting/
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 51, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\DataScience\venv\lib\site-packages\pandarallel\core.py", line 158, in __call__
    results = self.work_function(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\DataScience\venv\lib\site-packages\pandarallel\data_types\series.py", line 26, in work
    return data.apply(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\DataScience\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4433, in apply
    return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\DataScience\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 1082, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\DataScience\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 1137, in apply_standard
    mapped = lib.map_infer(
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2870, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\DataScience\glass_csv.py", line 15, in feature_extractor
    audio,sample_rate = librosa.load(file_name, res_type='kaiser_fast')
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\DataScience\glass_csv.py", line 29, in <module>
    metadata['mfccs_scaled_features'] = metadata['slice_file_name'].parallel_apply(feature_extractor)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\DataScience\venv\lib\site-packages\pandarallel\core.py", line 433, in closure
    results = results_promise.get()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
NameError: name 'os' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: never do: `from os  import *` as far as I could tell, you are not using it anyway. So consider deleting it. Not sure if this will solve yout problem though

Comment: thanks for say, but problem stays  still

Comment: Did you check the troubleshooting page it told you to check?

Comment: there  was not information about os  library

Comment: @datodatuashvili The troubleshooting page shows the exact scenario you are having issues with, just uses `math` in their example where you has `os`. Will probably apply for other the other bits outside of the function as well

Comment: i fixed problem  , i took some libraries out of  if statements, now it works

Answer (score 1):

i  solved it by trial and error( i mean just took some libraries out of if statement,like this

```
"""
audio_file ='UltraSound/100263-2-0-3.wav'
signal,sample_rate =librosa.load(audio_file)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
plt.plot(signal)
plt.show()
"""
import os
from os.path import join, abspath

Base_Directory = "UltraSound/"
# import os
# from os.path import  join,abspath
PATH = abspath(Base_Directory)
import numpy as np
import librosa
import librosa.display
import pandas as pd
if __name__ == '__main__':

    from multiprocessing import freeze_support
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    from pandarallel import pandarallel
    pandarallel.initialize()
    freeze_support()
    Base_Directory = "UltraSound/"
    #import os
    #from os.path import  join,abspath
    #PATH = abspath(Base_Directory)
    def feature_extractor(file_name):
        file_name = join(PATH, file_name)
        audio, sample_rate = librosa.load(file_name, res_type='kaiser_fast')
        mfccs_features = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40)
        mfccs_scaled_features = np.mean(mfccs_features.T, axis=0)
        return mfccs_scaled_features
    metadata = pd.read_csv('UltraSound/UrbanSound8K.csv')
    metadata['mfccs_scaled_features'] = metadata['slice_file_name'].parallel_apply(feature_extractor)
    print(metadata.head())
```

now everything is great :

```
C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\DataScience\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/DataScience/parallel_processing_audio.py
INFO: Pandarallel will run on 6 workers.
INFO: Pandarallel will use standard multiprocessing data transfer (pipe) to transfer data between the main process and workers.

WARNING: You are on Windows. If you detect any issue with pandarallel, be sure you checked out the Troubleshooting page:
https://nalepae.github.io/pandarallel/troubleshooting/
C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\DataScience\venv\lib\site-packages\librosa\util\decorators.py:88: UserWarning: n_fft=2048 is too small for input signal of length=1323
  return f(*args, **kwargs)
C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\DataScience\venv\lib\site-packages\librosa\util\decorators.py:88: UserWarning: n_fft=2048 is too small for input signal of length=1103
  return f(*args, **kwargs)
C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\DataScience\venv\lib\site-packages\librosa\util\decorators.py:88: UserWarning: n_fft=2048 is too small for input signal of length=1323
  return f(*args, **kwargs)
C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\DataScience\venv\lib\site-packages\librosa\util\decorators.py:88: UserWarning: n_fft=2048 is too small for input signal of length=1523
  return f(*args, **kwargs)
      slice_file_name  ...                              mfccs_scaled_features
0    100032-3-0-0.wav  ...  [-218.18938, 71.38549, -131.49442, -52.25892, ...
1  100263-2-0-117.wav  ...  [-425.05234, 110.67095, -54.192833, 62.045406,...
2  100263-2-0-121.wav  ...  [-459.82623, 122.82864, -47.908062, 53.302677,...
3  100263-2-0-126.wav  ...  [-414.82184, 102.94826, -36.65685, 54.170742, ...
4  100263-2-0-137.wav  ...  [-447.60776, 115.08627, -53.74607, 61.55309, 1...

[5 rows x 9 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

it finished so quickly (in google colab for one worker it took  50  minute and here just 2 minute)